# Reading the connected computer's drives from an Android App?

Tags: android

I would like to have an application sync itself with some files on a host computer.. Anyone know if this is possible? Eg: When you connect an Android phone to a computer i would like an application on the android system to read some allowed folders on the connected computer. Making it so the user doesn't have to sync files itself.

I ask possible, because i assume it isn't.. for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it solely from the Android end, because Windows doesn't make the local drives available through the USB port like that (unless you have some custom driver on the Windows side).

Your Android device will probably show up to windows as a USB drive. If you have an SD card plugged in, you may see a second drive from the Windows side.

To do something like this, you'd probably need to have software running on the Windows side that did the syncing, and then copy the data from the /sdcard directory on the Android device to wherever you ultimately need it to be.

Comment: Right, which is what i assumed. I also thought about the service on the computer side.. but i'm not sure i want to put users through that.

Anyway, thanks for the reply :)